# Why am I always getting the same output in this loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have the following function:

```
function mattes_create_matte_array(mattes, selected_type)
{
  ...

  $(mattes).each(function(i, el) //loop through the mattes xml
  {
    fillets = $(el).find("fillet")[0];
    console.log("i: " + i);
    if(typeof(fillets) !== "undefined")
    {
      switch (i)
      {
        case 0: fillet_selected_matte = "fillet_matte_layer_top"; console.log(fillet_selected_matte);break;
        case 1: fillet_selected_matte = "fillet_matte_layer_middle"; console.log(fillet_selected_matte);break;
        case 2: fillet_selected_matte = "fillet_matte_layer_bottom"; console.log(fillet_selected_matte);break;
      }


      fillet_change($(fillets).find("imgsrc").text(), $(fillets).find("cid").text(), $(fillets).find("sku").text());
    }

    ...
}
```

When I output fillet_selected_matte, I always get back "fillet_matte_layer_top", when I am expecting to output each "fillet_matte_layer_..."

console.log(el) is the following

```
<mat>
  <item size="0">
    <imgsrc>11852997eab43ff5c7b1803692bee608</imgsrc>
    <size>0</size>
    <cpu>20</cpu>
    <cid>4208</cid>
  </item>
  <fillet>
    <imgsrc>113a2584b32539ecdc35d70b39fde504</imgsrc>
    <width>0.31</width>
    <cid>9352</cid>
    <sku>TD00060S1</sku>
  </fillet>
</mat>
<mat>
    <item size="0.5">
    <imgsrc>579767cea6941301e6f91d43580a1948</imgsrc>
    <size>0.5</size>
    <cpu>0</cpu>
    <cid>4390</cid>
  </item>
    <fillet>
    <imgsrc>fee7ec5a4b50b65e94801682ae076a5a</imgsrc>
    <width>0.31</width>
    <cid>9348</cid>
    <sku>TD00052S0</sku>
  </fillet>
</mat>
<mat>
  <item size="0.5">
    <imgsrc>11852997eab43ff5c7b1803692bee608</imgsrc>
    <size>0.5</size>
    <cpu>0</cpu>
    <cid>42089349</cid>
  </item>
  <fillet>
    <imgsrc>5ade25e607b6302691c318a94792e6eb</imgsrc>
    <width>0.31</width>
    <cid>9349</cid>
    <sku>TD00060GL1</sku>
  </fillet>
</mat>
```

Here's the code for fillet_change:

```
function fillet_change(thumb, cid, sku)
{
  if (mattes_selected_type == 15) //letter mattes
  {
    alert("Fillets can only be applied to rectangular openings. Your current layout does not contain any rectangular openings, fillet was not applied");
    return;
  }
  var img = new Image();
  img.src =  SITE_URL + '/system/components/compimg/' + thumb + '/pattern';
  img.onload = function() 
  {
    width = .31;
    img.width = width * ppi; //TODO: Get actual width from xml?
    img.height = width * ppi; //TODO: Get actual width from xml?
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
      $("div[id^='opening_']").each(function(i) //for each div that has an id of opening_(number) 
      {
        //Set the values in the array with the width and height
        switch(fillet_selected_matte)
        {
          case "fillet_matte_layer_bottom": 
            moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width();
            moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height();
            index = 2;
            break;

          case "fillet_matte_layer_middle": 
            moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width() + 10;
            moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height() + 10;
            index = 1;
            break;

          case "fillet_matte_layer_top": 
            if (mattes_default_selected == true)
            {
              moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width() + 22;
              moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height() + 22;
            }
            else
            {
              moulding_matte_canvas_width[i] = $("#opening_" + i).width();
              moulding_matte_canvas_height[i] = $("#opening_" + i).height();
            }
            index = 0;
            break;
        }
        var parser = new DOMParser(); //create a new DOMParser
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(mattes_get_mattes_xml(), "application/xml"); //convert the string to xml
        doc.getElementsByTagName('fillet')[index].innerHTML = "<imgsrc>" + thumb + "</imgsrc><width>" + width + "</width><cid>" + cid + "</cid><sku>" + sku + "</sku>";
        var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); //create a new XMLSerializer
        mattes_mattes_xml = serializer.serializeToString(doc); //convert the xml back to a string

        common_get_order_xml();
        moulding_draw(img, "fillet"); //Call the moulding_draw function, which draws the fillet on the canvas
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Here's the code for moulding_draw:

```
function moulding_draw(img, fillet)
{
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("div[id^='opening_']").each(function(i) //for each div that has an id of opening_(number)
    {
      if (fillet == "fillet")
      {
        $("#fillet_canvas_" + fillet_selected_matte + "_" + i).remove(); //remove the selected filet canvas
      }
      else
      {
        $("#moulding_canvas").remove(); //remove the moulding canvas
      }

      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      if (fillet == "fillet")
      {
        canvas.id = "fillet_canvas_" + fillet_selected_matte + "_" + i; //create a fillet canvas for each element
        console.log(canvas.id);
      }
      else
      {
        canvas.id = "moulding_canvas";
      }
      canvas.style.position = "absolute";
      canvas.style.zIndex = 5;
      if (fillet == "fillet")
      {
        //Set the positioning of the fillets
        switch(fillet_selected_matte)
        {
          case "fillet_matte_layer_bottom": 
            fillet_bottom_left = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('left')) - img.width + "px"; 
            canvas.style.left = fillet_bottom_left;parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('top')) - img.width + "px";

            fillet_bottom_top = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('top')) - img.width + "px"; 
            canvas.style.top = fillet_bottom_top;
            break;

          case "fillet_matte_layer_middle": 
            fillet_middle_left = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('left')) - img.width - 5 + "px";
            canvas.style.left = fillet_middle_left;

            fillet_middle_top = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('top')) - img.width - 5 + "px"; 
            canvas.style.top = fillet_middle_top;
            break;

          case "fillet_matte_layer_top": 
            if (mattes_default_selected == true)
            {
              fillet_top_left = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('left')) - img.width - 12 + "px"; 
              canvas.style.left = fillet_top_left;

              fillet_top_top = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('top')) - img.width - 12 + "px"; 
              canvas.style.top = fillet_top_top;
            }
            else
            {
              fillet_top_left = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('left')) - img.width + "px";
              canvas.style.left = fillet_top_left;

              fillet_top_top = parseInt($("#opening_" + i).css('top')) - img.width + "px";
              canvas.style.top = fillet_top_top;
            }
            break;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        canvas.style.left = "-" + img.width + "px";
        canvas.style.top = "-" + img.height + "px"; 
      } 

      canvas.height = parseInt($("#matte_canvas").height()) + (img.height * 2);
      canvas.width = parseInt($("#matte_canvas").width()) + (img.width * 2);

      moulding_draw_elements(ctx, img, i); //call the function to actually draw the moulding elements

      if (fillet == "fillet")
      {
        $(canvas).insertAfter("#opening_" + i); //insert the canvas after the specific opening
      }
      else
      {
        $("#mattes").append(canvas); //appending the canvas
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why the votes to close?

Comment: Without the matching HTML the code is pretty useless. e.g. what is a `fillet` element?

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: Which of the logs are you actually getting? Maybe `fillets` is always undefined? Why do you have so many global variables?

Comment: I posted the xml of the "el" object

Comment: Thanks. Without that we had no clue it was XML driven.

Comment: what is in the `mattes` array ?

Comment: Found the cause, but cannot post an answer while the question is on hold. Just drop the indexing on `$(el).find("fillet")[i]` e.g. `$(el).find("fillet");` You are accessing child elements based on the parent's index! :) http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/BTHLZ/

Comment: There's only one `<fillet>` under each `<mat>`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Ugh, I assumed that is what he wanted to do?

Comment: Also after its initialization the variable "fillets" will never be `undefined`.

Comment: @fillet_change: That made no sense once the data was shown. (and I think `Alison`C may not be a *he* :)

Comment: What they are all trying to say is that you need to show your full code *for everyone to appreciate its charm* :)

Comment: Any chance of placing your code into the working JSFiddle provided below?

Comment: @Pointy - sometimes there are no fillets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the indexing on `$(el).find("fillet")[i]`

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/BTHLZ

e.g. to get the only DOM element (or undefined)

```
$(el).find("fillet")[0];
```

You were accessing child elements based on the parent's index, but there is only one `fillet` in each `mat` (maximum). Note the question has been changed, so this answer may make less sense now :)

Comment: I changed that but the call to fillet_change is only taking into account "fillet_matte_layer_bottom"

Comment: You do realise you *have not* provided that code don't you (for `fillet_change`)? :)

Comment: You have changed your code to have [0] which is correct as you wanted the DOM element, but now we need your fill example in JSFiddle as you are describing subsequent problems.

Comment: It's a big project that has a lot of code that depends on each other, otherwise I'd edit that jsfiddle

Comment: The immediate question was answered, and the question changed to incorporate it, but you appear to have a number of subsequent issues. Might be better off posting new questions as this one has mutated too much now from the original. "We" really need a JSFiddle example of the part that does not function.